# How do you translate "Oh woe is me"?

Tags: translation, phrase-requests, dative

The original phrasing is in yiddish, which is **Oy vey ist mir** (אױ װײ איז מיר). This is just a simply phrase that is said when something bad happens to oneself. According to google translate, the closest translation is *Ho ve al mi*, but this translation seems off to me. Is this the correct way for translating this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is.

> *Ho, ve al mi! morti en la brakoj de fremdulo!*
>
> Oh, woe is me! to die in the arms of a stranger!

That is from Zamenhof's own translation of Schiller's play *Die Räuber*. The original German reads

> *—weh mir! sterben in den Armen eines Fremdlings—*

Other examples show that the word *estas* can be included: e.g. *ve estas al la viro, kiu...*

Answer (score 6):

*Ho ve al mi* is fine.
*mir* is the singular first person pronoun in the **dative** case. English marks the dative with the preposition *to*, which in this translation was somehow left out. Esperanto marks it with the preposition *al*, thus *mir* translates to *al mi*. 
 The Esperanto translation leaves out the verb "to be", but I consider this a good choice, since the whole phrase is an interjection.